# Installing Apache Kudu on WSL

Tags: c++, gradle, cmake, apache-kudu

I am trying to install Apache Kudu and run the C++ examples on my Ubuntu distribution (18.04) on WSL. I am following the instructions for Ubuntu at https://kudu.apache.org/docs/installation.html

Everything runs smoothly until I get to step 6 where I run

```
make -j4
```

I get the following errors

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file  
     at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)                                                                            
     at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:225)                                                                       
     at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:155)                                                                       
     at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:169)                                                                       
     at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.unzip(Install.java:235)                                                                   
     at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.access$900(Install.java:27)                                                               
     at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:81)                                                                   
     at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)                                                                   
     at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:69)                             
     at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)                                                               
     at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:107)                                                 
     at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:63)                                         
CMakeFiles/init_gradle.dir/build.make:60: recipe for target '../../java/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar' failed       
make[2]: *** [../../java/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar] Error 1                                                     
make[2]: *** Deleting file '../../java/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar'                                               
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1708: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/init_gradle.dir/all' failed                                    
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/init_gradle.dir/all] Error 2                                                                   
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....                                                                            
[  5%] Built target kudu_util_pb_util_proto                                                                             
[  5%] Built target kudu_util_hash_proto                                                                                
[  6%] Built target hms_thrift                                                                                          
Makefile:140: recipe for target 'all' failed                                                                            
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

[Image of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ddiZy.png)

Does anybody know what is causing the errors?

Answer (score 0):

Happened to met same situation.
This exception is happened when building hms. And you can found verbose log by doing

```
cd <root_of_kudu>/java
./gradlew assemble
```

The problems I met is the zip of downloaded gradle seems wrong, so I cleaned `~/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-6.2.2-all/2k4hz1yffuhb6ob9prdg10tx/gradle-6.2.2-all.zip` and `<root_of_kudu>/java/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar`. And try to call `make -j4` again.

Further more, if you happened to have same bad network like mine, you can download the gradle zip manually, by checking the content of `<root_of_kudu>/java/gradlew`, the line with curl tells you the download link, try to download it with a good network or a proxy and then place it to the first path you cleaned, it may work.